# Running `kubectl exec` script from file is not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create a script in order to run multiple `kubectl exec` commands against multiple pods with multiple containers. The script seems to generate the command just fine but errors out when attempting to run it.

example command that is generated: `kubectl -n <namespace> exec <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- openssl version`

When I copy the generated command and run it directly it works fine, but if I try to run the command within the script I get an error.

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "openssl version": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

command terminated with exit code 126

snippet from .sh file:

```
for pod in $PODS; do
CONTAINERS=($(kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get pods $pod -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].name}' | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n'))
header "{pod: \"$pod\", containers: \"$(echo $CONTAINERS | tr -d '\n')\"}"

if [ "$DRYRUN" != "true" ]; then
    for container in $CONTAINERS; do
        echo "COMMAND BEING RUN: \"kubectl -n $NAMESPACE exec $pod -c $container -- $COMMAND\""
        kubectl -n $NAMESPACE exec $pod -c $container -- $COMMAND
    done
fi
done
```

Comment: Maybe pathing is incorrect when you are trying directly to run openssl. Have you tried to add a full path to your command?

Comment: based only upon the pasted output, I'm guessing you have quoted `COMMAND` so oci is looking for a binary named `"openssl command"`; running your script with `set -x` will show what it's actually substituting for `$COMMAND`, or you can cheat and `... -c $container -- sh -c $COMMAND` if that starts to work, then my theory was correct

Comment: tried with `-- sh -c $COMMAND` and getting the same error. Tried setting the full path as well but didn't work.

Comment: @cybersnow1989 see my answer posted below for the working fix, I ran into the exact same issue as you trying to run `openssl version` against all containers in all pods in all deployments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, this is *exactly* the problem I'm trying to solve. By any chance, are you trying to check OpenSSL versions on all containers due to the latest CVE's dropping yesterday? Because thats exactly what I'm trying to do.

Anyway, here is the solution - a problem in which I've had before and its down to the way sh/bash/zsh interprets strings.

It's hard to debug, as I'd need to see you're whole script instead of just the pod exec loop, but the underlying problem is: `$COMMAND` **cannot be placed into a string or used as a string**, otherwise your shell script will wrap it into a string and kubectl will interpret that as the whole thing being a command instead of correctly forwarding the breakpoints.

This is evident by the error message, its trying to interpret `openssl version` literally as a whole string that makes up the binary name you are trying to call, in which obviously `openssl version` isn't a command that will be on your `$PATH`, instead of correctly interpreting each command in the string and executing `openssl` which is on your `$PATH` with the `version` argument against it.

As I'm not sure if I've explained that very well, so to assist, here are some visual/working examples.

This **will not** work:

```
# ./my-script.sh openssl version
# Will OCI error as "openssl version" cannot be found in the containers $PATH

kubectl exec "${pod}" -c "${container}" -- "${@:1}"

COMMAND="${@:1}"

kubectl exec "${pod}" -c "${container}" -- $COMMAND

COMMAND=${@:1}

kubectl exec "${pod}" -c "${container}" -- "${COMMAND}"
```

This **will** work:

```
# ./my-script.sh openssl version
# LibreSSL 3.3.6

kubectl exec "${pod}" -c "${container}" -- ${@:1}

COMMAND=${@:1}

kubectl exec "${pod}" -c "${container}" -- $COMMAND
```

Simply put, if the command that you wish to forward is used as a string, it will not work.

Comment: While not exactly what I ended up with this pointed me in the right direction. Spellcheck plugin didn't like it though

Answer (score 3):

The command provided with `exec` will be executed without a shell. This means that environment variables will not be available. Thus the error specifying missing executable path in $PATH. Only executables installed in default `$PATH` (like `/bin/`) can be executed.

You can load the shell and provide `$command` as a command to be executed;

```
kubectl exec -n $NAMESPACE --container $container -it $pod -- /bin/sh -c "$COMMAND"
```

Comment: ran the above and am getting `kubectl exec -n account-engagement --container aec-consumer -it account-engagement-aec-consumer-66c774946f-qkhhx -- /bin/sh -c openssl version
/bin/sh: openssl: not found
command terminated with exit code 127`

Comment: when running with `set -x` however it seems that my command is being run with single quotes surrounding, that may be an issue.